# Does the Gem of Efficacious Toxin's debuff stack?

Tags: diablo-iii

If multiple party members have a Gem of Efficacious Toxin at rank 25+, will the "All enemies you poison take 10% increased damage from all sources" debuff stack? So when multiple people apply the DOT, do you see 10% damage increase or more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=35&v=Pg3YQFsKIoI) shows it stacking. [Mannercookie](http://www.twitch.tv/mannercookie) said he tested as well to confirm [here](http://www.diablofans.com/builds/59625-2-3-grift-exp-support-barb?comment=4). I've not seen any proof to refute this, just people saying the opposite in forums.

Answer (score 3):

My research indicates that you will see only a 10% damage increase.

[According to Wikia,](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Gem_of_Efficacious_Toxin) a mob can only have one of this gem's '10% increased damage taken' debuffs at a time, irrespective of how many players are applying it:

> At rank 25, it also increases damage the poisoned target takes from all sources (including other players), making this gem useful to classes focusing on elements other than Poison. If [t]his debuff is applied by more than one player, it will not stack.

This would appear to be backed up by [a discussion on the US Battle.net forums:](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/14057706254#11)

> are you referring to if all four in party uses the gem and have it at least 25%? then no, the 10% doesn't stack. mobs won't take 40%~ additional damage.